# MySQL group and sum with joined tables

Tags: mysql

I've got pretty tricky problem with MySQL.

I have two tables with one to many relation (below colums that are relevant)

Table A (campaigns):

```
id | channel_type | date
```

Table B (budgets):

```
id | campaign_id | budget
```

I need single query to fetch following result:

- Campaign count by channel_type
- Sum of all budgets that are related to found campaigns.

I need to filter results by columns in campaigns table (e.g. WHERE campaigns.date > '2014-05-01')

I have tried following approach:

```
SELECT channel_type, COUNT(*) cnt, 
   (SELECT SUM(budget) FROM budgets WHERE budgets.campaign_id = campaigns.id)) 
       as budget 
FROM campaigns 
WHERE campaigns.date >= 'some-value' 
    AND [more conditions] 
GROUP BY campaigns.channel_type
```

But this of course fails miserably because of GROUP i am getting only first campaigns.id result for channel_type.

Any tips (and solution) would be really appreciated!

TIA

Comment: set this up in [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and i'll help

Comment: If you're still interested i've put it in fiddle: [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5e42/5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found working solution.
Here's working query:

```
SELECT SUM(budget) as budget, COUNT(*) as count FROM
    (SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE [conditions]) AS found_campaigns
    LEFT JOIN budgets ON budgets.campaign_id = found_campaigns.id
    GROUP BY channel_type
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the total budget from budgets table using GROUP BY campain_id. It will be subquery. Name it. For example, A.
2. Now get the total id counts from campains using GROUP BY channel_type and WHERE date>='some-value'.
3. Use step 2 and 1(the subquery will act as table) in the final query and you will get the results.
   You can post schema and then I can check.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work :

```
SELECT channel_type, COUNT(*) cnt, 
   (SELECT SUM(t2.budget) FROM budgets t2 WHERE t2.campaign_id IN (
     SELECT t3.id FROM campaigns t3 WHERE t3.channel_type = t1.channel_type)) 
   AS budget 
FROM campaigns t1
WHERE t1.date >= 'some-value' 
    AND [more conditions] 
GROUP BY t1.channel_type
```

see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89d50/8)

Comment: Works as expected :) I am wondering how fast it will be. I've heard somewhere that IN with subquery is not very efficient. However im too noobish in SQL to confirm nor propose better solution anyways. Will run some benchmarks at work tommorow with large dataset. Thanks

Comment: I've analysed your solution and it's not working as expected. In main query you're using channel_type that is fed to second subquery to fetch campaign IDs. Hovewer this skips WHERE condition. Condition counts campaigns with specific date condition. Takes their channel_types and then fetches ALL campaigns with found channel_type and feeds them to SUM(budget) query. So if we have 10 campaigns of type "1" and WHERE plunks out 2 of them count is fine (2) but budget is calculated for all (10) campaigns of channel type "1".

Comment: Why don't you just add a date condition to the subquery ?
SELECT t3.id FROM campaigns t3 WHERE t3.channel_type = t1.channel_type AND t3.date >= t1.date

Comment: In actual query there will be around 5 conditions: (date_start BETWEEN date1 AND date2)

Comment: sqlfiddle seems to be down. But you need to match your query conditions in the subquery, even if you have 5 conditions

Comment: Actual production:
    SELECT channel_type, COUNT(*) as activity,
    (SELECT SUM(scb.budget) FROM sub_campaign_budget scb WHERE scb.sub_campaign_id IN (
        SELECT t3.id FROM sub_campaign t3 WHERE t3.channel_type = t.channel_type)
    ) AS budget 
    FROM `sub_campaign` `t` 
    LEFT JOIN `campaign` ON `campaign`.`id` = `t`.`campaign_id` 
    WHERE
    (`t`.`ends_on` BETWEEN '2011-10-01' AND '2016-04-08') 
    OR 
    (`t`.`starts_on` BETWEEN '2011-10-01' AND '2016-04-08') 
    AND `t`.`franchise_id` = 5
... damn. ill just setup it on SQL fiddle

Comment: Yeah. It's down. Anyways there are lots of conditions in query and additional JOIN. I wanted to avoid copying conditions in two queries (main and second sub for budgets). There must be (or at least would be sensible to think so :) ) way to fetch only once filtered IDs and feed them to count and sum subqueries. By copying conditions i effectivly ask db for same data set twice. Second subquery will be just like the first one only used for something else. That doesnt seem efficient. But maybe thats the only way in SQL world.